# Triggering an HTTP request after purchase on Play Store / App Store

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm currently working on an application that sells in-app content and I'm looking for a way to **trigger an HTTP Request on my API when the purchase is finished.**

After going through the documentation of the **Play Store** and the **App Store**, I didn't find anything of the sort.

Do you know if anything of this kind exists and where can I find documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt)? What you seem to be specifically looking for is [onPurchasesUpdated](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Enable), the method that is triggered when a purchase completes. If the purchase was successful you get a `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK` and you should make your HTTP Request call to your API there. If the purchase was not successful, then the response code is something else that explains the error.

Comment: I saw this method, but I was wondering if (the server of ?) Google could trigger my API.

Like, someone is buying an in-app content but he kills the application after paying for the content. In this case, I would like Google to trigger my API

Comment: Google Play Billing always sends a trigger to your Android app. But your Android app will receive it only if it is active, but if it's killed then it won't get the trigger. However we do provide a server-to-server solution whereby you always receive a trigger no matter what. Have you taken a look at Realtime Developer Notifications? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications